# Why is this site's suggested edit queue size different from the network default?

Tags: support, editing

On all sites, the suggested edit review queue has a fixed size, and no suggested edits are accepted from anyone if it's full. The queue size is 40 on all other SE sites [besides Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351728/447356), but is customized to [50 on this site](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5152797#5152797).

I don't understand why it's customized on this site. The (then-)employee who queried the code [said they had no idea why it was customized](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5152817#5152817), and I couldn't find anything when searching this meta site.

Why is the size of the suggested edit review queue customized on this site to 50, instead of the network default 40? Was there an issue at one point that resulted in it being increased as a temporary measure, which just stuck later?

Comment: What is an edit review queue?

Comment: @Ragaroni Users who don't have enough reputation to make edits to posts on the main site can "suggest" edits to posts, and their edit proposals will be placed into a queue where users who do have enough reputation can approve or reject them. This queue has a size limit; if there are more than [queue size] pending suggested edits, others won't be able to suggest edits until some of them get reviewed. See the [FAQ on suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) on the global meta.